# Get my CSS boxes to look correct with percentage width and margin.

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to making some content fit nicely into another container.

My CSS: (The boxes that say 'test' are id='resultBox')

```
#resultBox{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:20%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

But this looks bad, it's all cramped, however, I want there to be 5 boxes per line, is there a way I can give a margin, and make it automatically adjust the width%?

Picture related: The top one is the margin I want, but the bottom is the behaviour I want. 
[image]

Comment: So you want 5 boxes across with a 1px margin on each?

Comment: I know it might sounds like blasphemy to some, but have you considered using a table?  Afterall, tables are designed to present tabular data.  Also you should be using a class to apply your styling rather than an id.  Id's are designed to be unique not the same id for multiple elements.

Comment: SO do you have multiple elements with the same ID or am I reading that wrong. If you do then you should change that as an ID is a unique identifier and should only be used for one element per page. Use a class instead. You could also make the margin a percentage such as 1% and and make the elements themselves 19% width.

Comment: id should be unique to a single element on the page. For multiple elements with the same styling use class

Comment: I'm sorry, ir eally should have clarified, the id was for some testing I was doing, didn't wnat to dirty up my real css.  Anyway, @BillyMoat, that solution isn't a good one, because 1% is often MUCH larger than 1 pixel.

Comment: A bit of a workaround but gets the visual result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/LRuUd/

Comment: If the containing div has a fixed width, you can simply calculate it from that. So for a container of `width:500px;` you would set `width:99px` for `#resultbox` with `margin-left:1px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this table-less table implementation?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xKj8n/

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div><span>Test</span></div>
        <div><span>Test</span></div>
        <div><span>Test</span></div>
        <div><span>Test</span></div>
        <div><span>Test</span></div>
    </div>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

You can also do this without rows if you're willing to [sacrifice compatibility with IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) and use `nth-child()` selectors (you could always apply classes using JavaScript):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xKj8n/2/

```
<div id="table">
    <div><span>Test</span></div>
    <div><span>Test</span></div>
    <div><span>Test</span></div>
    <div><span>Test</span></div>
    <div><span>Test</span></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: This also stacks a bit nicer when you clear the floats at the `.row` level using `.row { clear: both; }`: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xKj8n/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you are only supporting newer browsers then use `box-sizing: border-box`

This will include the padding and border inside the width. Don't use margin, use the border to give things an appearance of spacing.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: [No compatibility in IE7 or before](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing), but that's pretty [cross-browser friendly](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate a margin like you want by using an [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline):

```
#resultBox {
    ...
    outline: 1px solid white;
    ...
}
```

This way you would have the visual definition of each block, without bumping the right-most one down to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `box-sizing: border-box` with 1px borders on the right and bottom, but you'll also need to use `:nth-child` to remove the extra 1px from the rightmost boxes.

```
.box
{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box:nth-child(5n)
{
    border-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pf2LZ/

This should work in reasonable browsers and IE8+. IE8 only (I think) will have an extra pixel on the right-hand side due to a lack of support for `:nth-child`. You could always tack an extra class on every fifth element if that's an issue.

Comment: Though I can see this working in that jsfiddle, this is NOT working on my code.  I'm at a bit of a loss right now...

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a table if you are trying to display tabular data.

```
td { 
    width: 20%;
    text-transform:uppercase; }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This would add a level of complication because the boxes are being generated using jquery's masonry plugin.

Comment: Would this work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659744/get-my-css-boxes-to-look-correct-with-percentage-width-and-margin/11660008#11660008

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your browser requirements are, but you could try the new CSS3 Flexbox module:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/